# How can I create a multi-indexed pandas dataframe within a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a weekly time-series of multiple varibles and I am trying to view what percentrank the last 26week correlation would be in vs. all previous 26week correlations.

So I can generate a correlation matrix for the first 26wk period using the pd.corr function in pandas, but I dont know how I can loop through all previous periods too find the different values for these correlations to then rank.

I hope there is a better way to achieve this if so please let me know

I have tried calculating parallel dataframes but i couldnt write a formula to rank the most recent - so i beleive that the solution lays with multi-indexing.

'''python

```
    daterange = pd.date_range('20160701', periods = 100, freq= '1w')
np.random.seed(120)
df_corr = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,5), index= daterange, columns = list('abcde'))

df_corr_chg=df_corr.diff()
df_corr_chg=df_corr_chg[1:]
df_corr_chg=df_corr_chg.replace(0, 0.01)

d=df_corr_chg.shape[0]
df_CCC=df_corr_chg[::-1]

for s in range(0,d-26):
    i=df_CCC.iloc[s:26+s]
```

I am looking for a multi-indexed table showing the correlations at different times

Example of output
e.g. (formatting issues)

```
          a         b
a   1 1         -0.101713 
    2 1         -0.031109 
    n 1          0.471764
b   1 -0.101713  1
    2 -0.031109  1
    n 0.471764   1
```

Comment: Could you maybe describe a bit better, what your correlation matrix should look like? the 1,2,3 are the weeks, right? and you want to have the 26 last weeks? but what are the columns then? the average exchange rate of the last 26 weeks? if so, I guess the correlation of 1 between the average and the single weeks would be unrealistic, right?

Comment: Hi, the example given was for output so 1, 2, 3, each signify a correaltion for the first 1,2 and 3 26week periods. The columns and rows are both the assets - and correlation of 1 is because the variables have exactly the same differences (in this case it is the same variable).

Comment: Does your dataframe just contain one price per symbol and week? and are your weeks numbered or do you have just dates?

Comment: A sample of the input data would probably be helpful.

Comment: The dataframe has over 500 weekly changes for 20 plus variables and the weeks are given in date value

Comment: Do you only have one row per week and symbol? Please add some data.

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the df_corr_chg dataframe if that helps?

Comment: It's a good start, thank you, but probably nobody would enjoy to type the data from a screenshot :-)

Comment: Applogies, I have edited and cleaned the code to provide data

Comment: No problem, but thank you :-) because it probably will also help, in case someone else finds your question while searching for a solution to their problem, so it also will be easier to judge, if it is the same sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a receipe how you could approach the problem.
I assume, you have one price per week (otherwise just preaggregate your dataframe).

```
# in case you your weeks are not numbered
# Sort your dataframe for symbol (EUR, SPX, ...) and week descending. 
df.sort_values(['symbol', 'date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
# Now add a pseudo 
indexer= df.groupby('symbol').cumcount() < 26
df.loc[indexer, 'pricecolumn'].corr()
```

One more hint, in case you need to preaggregate your dataframe. You could add another aux column with the week number in your frame like:

```
df['week_number']=df['datefield'].dt.week
```

Then I guess you would like to have the last price of each week. You could do that as follows:

```
df_last= df.sort_values(['symbol', 'week_number', 'date'], ascending=True, inplace=False).groupby(['symbol', 'week_number']).aggregate('last')
df_last.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Then use `df_last` in in place of the `df` above. Please check/change the field names, I assumed.